# Concrete5 Securimage - image not refreshing on click

Tags: captcha, contact-form, concrete5

I'm trying to build my own contact form with Securimage. In my view.php, I have this:

```
<div>
<img id="captcha_img" src="<?php echo $this->action('securimage'); ?>" /> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#captcha_img').click(function(){ 
        $(this).attr('src', '<?php echo $this->action('securimage'); ?>&time=' + (new Date).getTime());
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

but when I click on it on the image it disappears instead of being reloaded.

My controller.php has this code for the securimage:

```
public function action_securimage() {
  Loader::library('3rdparty/securimage/securimage');
  $this->securimage = new Securimage();
  $this->securimage->show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Will really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good you just need to make a minor change from:

```
$(this).attr('src', '<?php echo $this->action('securimage'); ?>&time=' + (new Date).getTime());
```

to

```
$(this).attr('src', '<?php echo $this->action('securimage'); ?>?time=' + (new Date).getTime());
```

You need to change the `&` to `?` to properly add the random value to the query string and not part of the URL.